# Несколько регистраций в одну запись лида WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на вордпресс. Есть несколько полей в форме заявки. Например имя и почта. В другой форме есть дополнительные поля: компания, адрес сайта, телефон и тд. Нужно сделать так, чтобы если клиент заполнил первую форму и вторую форму, его данные добавлялись в админку в одну запись лида. То есть чтобы он был одним клиентом. Если он заполнил только имя и почту - в записи остаются только имя и почта. Если ещё дополнительные поля - то в записе остаются все поля.

Может есть какие-то плагины уже ? Нуждаюсь в совете, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Отправить одновременно 2 формы нельзя. Создавай во второй нужные поля или же в первую добавляй дополнительные необязательные.
В общем делай одну форму.

Для записи данных из форм в базу есть плагины-дополнения для плагинов-формбилдеров. Напр. для [СF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) есть [несколько плагинов](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Contact+Form+7+db/)